# Camaron (v1.10.19) on ropstent testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten

I'm using geth version Sharblu (v1.10.18) on Ropsten testnet (POS) with consensus client, but now i need update geth to version Camaron (v1.10.19)
Can i run geth lastest version Camaron (v1.10.19) on Ropsten testnet? And what do I need to do?
AFAIK, Gray Glacier will not be deployed on any testnet https://blog.ethereum.org/2022/06/16/gray-glacier-announcement/
help me explain it!!! thank you